# Random numbers generated using uniform real distribution in C++ are not really uniformly distributed

Tags: c++, random

I wrote a small code to make sure that I can get random numbers from a really wide range, ex. [0, 10^36) because I am going to use these wide ranges later.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{   unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    double expo = pow(10,36);
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0,expo);
    std::mt19937_64 rng(seed);
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        std::cout << dist(rng) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And the following is an example of the output:

```
6.75507e+035
4.01129e+035
6.85525e+035
8.85896e+035
3.1455e+035
3.04962e+035
5.48817e+035
3.54502e+035
2.24337e+035
2.23367e+035
```

As you can see, the random numbers are all really close to the upper endpoint of the given interval. I tried running the program lots of times, also increased 10 numbers to 100, but the random numbers were always close to the upper endpoint of the interval (with the exponent 35, and sometimes 34).

Since I have used `std::uniform_real_distribution`, I expect to have also and sometimes the numbers in the range [0, 1000] for example. I do not find this a uniform distribution. This is important to me that the random number is not only close to the upper endpoint because I am going to use the random number later in an if-statement:

```
if (random_number == 0)
    //do some operations
```

And the upper endpoint will be actually used as a rate, in which something occurs. But it seems that the random number has no chance to be zero sometimes.

I do not know why this happens and would really appreciate any idea or help.

(Eclipse 4.4.1, Windows 7)

Comment: If `std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0,1000)(rng)` returns (exactly) 1000.0, then there is a bug in your implementation and it should be reported, since the interval is supposed to be half-closed: `[0, 1000)`. Returning 0 is possible, but the probability is microscopic, probably less than one in a quadrillion.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> As you can see, the random numbers are all really close to the upper
>   endpoint of the given interval.

No, they're not. This one, for example:

```
2.23367e+035
```

Note that in the range `[0, 1e36]`, the sub-range `[1e35, 1e36]` is 9 times as large as the sub-range `[0, 1e35]`, so with a uniform distribution, you can expect to see those numbers 9 times as often. You will see numbers with an exponent of 34 now and then, but exponents any lower get exceedingly rare.

Comment: That's right! I hadn't thought about that... So that means it is really a uniform distribution.
Thank you Benjamin!

Answer (score 4):

Benjamin Lindley's answer is good.  I'd like to add that you might be looking for a different kind of distribution instead of a uniform distribution.  You could write it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0, 36);
    std::mt19937_64 rng(seed);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        std::cout << pow(10, dist(rng)) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That program gives me the following output:

```
7.26972e+027
5.97e+010
3.50003e+034
3.42446e+021
2.93422e+035
111.724
2.73858e+019
55641.4
4.18253e+019
7.47441e+007
9.2706
7.45588e+009
3.26219e+007
5.6794e+027
4.67289e+026
4.24672e+014
3.97334e+010
14.7511
2.65037e+022
85279.3
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but as I mentioned earlier, I should use the upper endpoint later as a rate, so I am not allowed to change it. :/ But thanks anyway!

Comment: I didn't change the upper endpoint, which is still 10^36.  I accidentally changed the lower endpoint from 0 to 1 though.

Comment: You're right. But what I mean from the rate in my code is, for example for random_number=1, the probability with which this random number is generated is 1/10^36. Such a probability in your code is 1/35 * 1/10^dist(rng) . Since actually the probability is my purpose and not the random numbers themselves, I couldn't use your code although I believe that was an interesting idea if I didn't have the limitation of considering the probability.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the math of the situation, it is much more likely that a number will have the exponent `10^35` because of the possible numbers in each range:

- There are `9*10^34` different numbers in the range `[1*10^35,1*10^36)`
- There are `9*10^33` different numbers in the range `[1*10^34,1*10^35)`
- There are `1000` different numbers in the range `[1,1000]`

So you can see that it is `10` times more likely for a number to have the exponent `10^35` than `10^34` and it is `9*10^32` times more likely for a number to have the exponent `10^35` than to be in the range `[1,1000]`.